# JQuery: Remove element added dynamically

Tags: jquery, dynamic, element

I've got a popup window that allows me to select an image and returns the image name to the parent window as an line element in a list. I want to add a remove link to the end of the line so that line is removed individually.

Main page:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ImageManager').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var w = window.open("/image-manager", "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".remove").on("click", function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
    </script>

<ul id="imagelist">
</ul>
<a href="" class="ImageManager">Add Image</a>
```

Image Manger Popup:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".addimage").click(function() {
            var imgname = $('img', this).attr("alt");
            $("#imagelist", window.opener.document).append('<li>' + imgname + '<a class="remove">Remove</a></li>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the popup the image name is stored in the alternative text. When I click remove in the main page nothing happens. Been down the other SO posts with the same titles but can't find a similar solution.

Answer (score 5):

That would be an element that is added after the DOM is ready, so it's dynamic, and you'll need a delegated event handler :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ImageManager').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var w = window.open("/image-manager", "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
    });

    $("#imagelist").on("click", ".remove", function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Using this removes all the lines in the list, not just the one where the remove link is found. Probably still an error in my code but I can't see it.

Comment: Check your HTML, this targets the parent element of the clicked anchor, and removes it. If it removes all the lines, you have errors in your markup making the parent element something that contains all the lines ?

Comment: Checked my HTML, surely the li tags are the parent of the anchor. I'd presume that only the one set of li tags (opening and closing) are removed rather than every set?

Comment: I tried using $(this).closest('li').remove(); instead of the parent option used in the code above. The entire list still clears. I've double checked the HTML and tried using Firebug but can't see a reason the whole list clears.